# Laravel fetch relation of relation without using a loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

Right now I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm trying to optimize old code using more of laravels convention instead of fabricating my own loops in order to get the data I need.

So here's what I have right now:

Region Model

```
class Region extends Eloquent {
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function vms() {
        return $this->hasMany('Vm');
    }
}
```

Game Model

```
class Game extends Eloquent {
    public $table = 'vm_games';

    public function vm() {
        return $this->hasOne('Vm');
    }
}
```

Vm Model

```
class Vm extends Eloquent {    
    public function games() {
        return $this->hasMany('Game');
    }
}
```

Now what I want currently do is the following:

```
$games = 0;
foreach($region->vms()->where('status', true)->get() as $vm) {
    $games += $vm->games()->where('created_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 5400))->count();
}

$sorted[$region->id]->games = $games;
```

Now ofcourse using Laravels Eloquent relations is much cleaner:

```
$region->vms()->where('status', true)->count();
```

Now what I want to do is something like this:

```
$games = $region->vms()->where('status', true)->games();
```

This wont work obviously, I have also tried playing around with "with" and "whereHas" but to no avail.

I really hope you could help me out.

Kind regards,
Niek

Comment: If you would like to add conditional in relation between, i don't think so you are able to do that simple. Laravel support relations through ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through ) but i am not sure if you will able to use it in your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this, using eager loading and pluck():

```
$games = Region::with(['vms' => function($query) {
    $query->where('status', true);
}, 'vms.games'])->get()->pluck('vms.games');
```

Comment: Interesting way, I'll try it out as asap. Thank you. Ps. I don't mind iterating through the objects to form my own collection, just trying to improve upon aswell :)